# How to make javascript comment out code with more than 100 lines collapseable

Tags: visual-studio

In visual studio code, I tried to comment out my javascript code so that I don't need to copy and past multiple times when I try something else on the same file.

I tried the method of `/* code */` and `// code`. While they are collapsable when used seperately by non comment content, they automatically disable the collapsable status upon adding them comment consecutively.

How can I work around this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I have find the solution to it.
Before commenting them, make sure it is already collapsed.
Then comment them multiple lines of code like below.

```
/*
code
*/
```

Instead of this

```
/*code*/
```

The new line matters as it makes the auto disable collapseable problem disappear.